# Как работать с C# на Ubuntu?

Tags: c#, windows, ubuntu, кросс-компиляция

Недавно после перехода с Windows на Linux у меня возникла задача разрабатывать с С# простые приложения и тесты. 
Меня интересует вопрос, если аналоги Visual Studio для Ubuntu?

Comment: Появились какие нибудь альтернативы на данный момент ?

Comment: Собственно [Rider](https://www.jetbrains.com/rider/), правда есть опасность что вы решите отказаться от VS и на винде).
В связке с [.NET Core](https://www.microsoft.com/net/learn/get-started/linuxubuntu) работает прекрасно.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Mono — проект по созданию полноценного воплощения системы .NET Framework на базе свободного программного обеспечения. Есть возможность разработки на C# под `Android` и так же аналог `WPF`.

[Ссылка на сайт проекта.](http://www.mono-project.com/)

Comment: вангую за моно. Можно и не только разрабатывать на c#, но и на c++ и бэйсике :). А вот про андроид не знал. Можно по подробнее, как в моно под андроид заниматься разработкой? (ссылки и т.п.)

Comment: @MaxZS: Xamarin же!

Comment: @VladD Причем здесь одно к другому, тем более на Ubuntu? Xamarin основан на Mono и использует его компилятор. Но Xamarin нет на Ubuntu. По крайней мере до ближайшего недавнего времени. А после приобретения Xamarin Майкрософтом, думаю, что можно будет забыть про развитие в сторону linux вообще.

Comment: @MaxZS: Я имею в виду на Xamarin Studio, а Xamarin как набор библиотек. В качестве IDE всё равно выбор обычно между vi и emacs.

Comment: @VladD так где можно увидеть и скачать набор библиотек Xamarin для Ubuntu (под Linux)?

Comment: @MaxZS: А библиотеки кроссплатформенные, это ж .NET. Отдельных под Убунту нет.

Comment: @VladD А кроме теоретических измышлений можно ссылочку на то, как я могу используя набор библиотек Xamarin и Ubuntu смогу скомпилировать программу под Андроид?

Comment: @MaxZS: Извините, не специалист ни в Андроиде, ни в Убунту, ни в Замарине. Но где конкретно вы видите возможные препятствия? Отсутствие готовой среды, которая запустит нужные компиляторы с нужными флагами?

Comment: @VladD Проблема в том, что кроссплатформенность не подразумевают работу абсолютно на всем. Если под конкретную платформу нет каких-то библиотек - значит их нет. Нельзя взять программу, написанную, например, на C# с использованием WinForms под Win и скомпилировать ее в Мono на Linux. Почему? Да потому что нет соответствующих библиотек. На Linux идет вместо WinForms GTK. И сама платформа .NET здесь не при чем. Вот в чем я вижу проблему.

Comment: @MaxZS: Ну, вы ж можете из-под Windows скомпилировать .NET-проект с Xamarin'овскими библиотеками? И он при этом, понятно, будет работать на Android'е. Ну так вы тот же самый код вполне можете скомпилировать с теми же самыми библиотеками и под Ubuntu/Mono, правильно? WinForms — windows-специфическая библиотека, но скомпилировать winforms-проект вы можете и под Ubuntu, были бы DLL-ки. А вот запустить его, понятно, вы сможете только под Windows. Ну так вы ведь не рассчитывали запустить Android-проект под Ubuntu без эмулятора?

Comment: @VladD ...а запустить скомпилированный проект я должен иметь возможность не под Win, а под Андроид. И да... В Lin нет dll, здесь so. И простая подмена одних на другие не проходит.

Comment: @MaxZS: http://www.mono-project.com/docs/faq/technical/#is-mono-binary-compatible-with-windows

Comment: @VladD Я не спрашиваю в общем о Моно. У меня установлена Kubuntu, установлена Mono develop и я знаю, что простые консольные приложения я могу компилировать и запускать и на lin и на win. Но я спрашиваю конкретно про библиотеки Xamarin для разработки под мобильные платформы. И по Вашей ссылке я читаю, что не все API реализованы (и это они, как я понимаю, пишут про стандартный набор, не говоря уже о дополнительных библиотеках).

Comment: @MaxZS: По ссылке написано, что Mono реализует не все функции, работающие в Microsoft .NET. Но Xamarin на Андроиде всё равно использует Mono, так что насколько мне кажется совершенно всё равно, будете ли вы компилировать из-под Windows или из-под Ubuntu: на целевой системе будут использованы одни и те же Mono-библиотеки.

Comment: Нельзя в линуксе писать на WPF. Нет там такого. Только формами. Делал я пару-тройку проектиков на шарпе в линуксе. Все хорошо, пока делаешь стандартные вещи. Шаг в право или лево - расстрел! :)

Comment: @Michael WPF нет. Но есть Avalonia, хотя конечно лучше бы чистый WPF

Comment: @vitidev Спасибо! Пров Авалонию не знал..

Answer (score 7):

[Visual Studio Code](https://code.visualstudio.com/) работает и на Ubuntu.

Скачиваете. распаковываете из архива и запускаете code.

Альтернативно можете использовать Ubuntu Make:

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:ubuntu-desktop/ubuntu-make
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install ubuntu-make
```

После чего установить Visual Studio

```
umake ide visual-studio-code
```

или

```
umake web visual-studio-code
```

Можно вместо Mono использовать кроссплатформенный .Net Core

Альтернативно можете использовать Xamarin и писать кроссплатформенные мобильные приложения.

Comment: Visual Studio Code не более чем хороший блокнот.

Answer (score 1):

Atom конечно же, да, это редактор текста, но расширяемость плагинами, поддержка GitHub , огромное коммунити и функции делают его чуть ли не полноценным IDE

Comment: Надеюсь это замотивирует вас кодить лучше.